# do-release-upgrade fails with ubuntu 16.04 with plesk installed

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, dependencies, php, php7

I have an older Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS server with Plesk Obsidian 18.0.34 Update #2 and I am trying to upgrade to 18.04 LTS. Everything is up to date but when I execute `do-release-upgrade` it complains that `An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade`.

I tried many things including marking certain packages as auto installed so apt is more likely to suggest a removal instead of trying to keep hold of them but no luck so far.

As far as I can tell, the main problem is that apt wants to install `php7.0-curl` which depends on `libcurl3` but since other components need `libcurl4` this is impossible. I have no idea what needs `php7.0-curl` as `apt rdepends php7.0-curl` only gives me `php-curl` which would anyway be updated to use `php7.2-curl`.

`/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log`: https://pastebin.com/zaH7zBJD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output seems pretty clear: Plesk packages are *directly* causing 12  of the 14 broken package errors. Plesk is the problem.

Also see https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002913773-Ubuntu-18-04-support-in-Plesk: Plesk does not support release-upgrade.

> Plesk supports Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver) starting from Plesk Onyx 17.8.
>
> Notes:
>
> - Currently, dist-upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 with Plesk installed is not supported.
> - Plesk Installer deploys MariaDB by default. In order to have MySQL as a database server, install MySQL prior to the Plesk Installer initializing.

Suggested procedure:

1. Backups
2. Uninstall all Plesk packages
3. do-release-upgrade
4. If needed, install MySQL
5. Re-install Plesk

Another alternative is to clean-install Ubuntu 20.04 in Step #3. See https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015594400-Ubuntu-20-04-support-in-Plesk for Plesk release notes on 20.04.